# Compiling code only when it's needed

Tags: function, math, hash, compilation, metadata

I am making a program that compiles code from one language to another. e.g. codefile.lang1 => codefile.lang2

I want the compiling to happen every time the program starts, but only if it is needed, in other words, only if changes were made since the last compiling.

My guess is that i need to include in the compiled code (codefile.lang2) some kind of metadata that stores a "summarization" of the contents of the pre-compiled code (codefile.lang1).
Lets say that the function that does the "summarization" of the pre-compiled code is F.
My idea is that every time the program starts, it will evaluate F(pre-compiled code) and compare it to the metadata in the compiled code,

if F == metadata: no need for compiling, else, compile.

It follows that F has to be injective (one to one function) for obvious reasons.
Also, i trying to avoid the trivial implementation, i.e. F(some code) = some code

Is that a good approach? If so, what should i use for F?
I thought about hashing, but hashing is not completely injective, especially for large texts.

What are your suggestions?
Thanks :)

Comment: it depends on the language most likely, a hash of the source code would be a way to start though

Comment: What do you mean by depends on the language?
Does it depend on the syntax? or the length?
Also, maybe hashing is a good way to start but it is not something that i would to implement in a final product given that it is not perfect.
I want to avoid collisions completely.

Comment: If I add a comment. you don't need to recompile. The symbol for a comment changes between languages

Comment: I want to neglect comments for the time being because unnecessary recompiling is not a big problem in my case. As long as the user doesn't add/remove comments every run, it shouldn't be a problem.
So putting comments aside, is hashing a good approach for the problem?

Comment: I'll write it up in an answer for youu

Comment: Just check the timestamps on the files, if the compiled is different from the source, it is rather easy. You can get a lot more complicated, but that works 95% of the time.

Comment: @leppie good point. mind if I add that to my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this is to cache the last compiled source code, and compare the new source code with that. If there's been a change, you should recompile.

A more efficient way would be to store a hash of the original source code, and compare this against the hash of the new source code, which will achieve the same as the above, but be substantially more efficient for large source files.

Whist you can theoretically get a hash collision, in practice it's not something you need to think about (assuming you're using a decent hash with enough entropy). The chances are just *that* low! [Do the maths, and you'll see](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/). If you're really paranoid, you can check the size or length of the file matches too.

In the future, you could also add language specific enhancements, which check if the only changes are things that have no effect on the executable code generated (i.e. comments and formatting), but this is likely to be slower than just recompiling the file.

---

As @leppie mentioned, you can also factor in the timestamp of the file.

Comment: The first approach, F(some code) = some code, is what i try to avoid exactly for the reason you (more efficient for large source files).
But what i want to achieve eventually is something collision proof, something that won't skip compiling in case it is needed.
And what i've heard about most hashing functions is that they're not completely injective and for large texts there is a chance for collision.
Are you sure that hashing will work at least 99.99999% of the time?

Comment: @Arik well, put it this way, git uses hashes to store commits, and the entire linux kernel is checked using those hashes, so whilst theoretically it's possible, you can ignore it ;) Just make sure you use a decent hash

Comment: @Arik I've updated my answer to give you some more info

Comment: Ok, i think i will take you advise, what's a decent hash? sha1? md5? I'm not really familiar with hashing that much.
I also think about storing the length of the source code in the metadata alongside with the hash, it won't make it perfect but it will probably make the hashing more durable for collisions.

Edit: I just read your updated answer, i understand now that hashing is probably the way to go.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Arik you don't need a cryptographically secure hash, so I think that'd be overkill. I don't know my hashes that well, so I think it'd be a bad idea for me to advice a specific one.